# Is it possible to debug a COM dll in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, com, com-interop

This may be a very stupid question.
Is it possible to debug a COM dll in VS2008 for which I do not have the source code?

The reason I want to do this is I am passing an Array to a COM method and I expect this Array to be populated by the method.
However the Array is not being populated. So I want to step into the COM method to see whats happening. is this possible?

Below is an example of the code I am using:

```
Array binaryArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(sbyte), 896);
bool success = photo.GetBinaryData(binaryArray);
```

IDL for the `GetBinaryData` method:

```
[id(0x000000c9)]
HRESULT GetBinaryData(
                [in] SAFEARRAY(char) buffer, 
                [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* retval);
```

The `GetBinaryData` method is the COM method which I would like to step into.

**EDIT: Adding a Delphi test script which works**

```
procedure TComTestForm.TestUserBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  nCnt :integer;
  User :IUser;
  Persona :IUserPersona;
  ArrayBounds :TSafeArrayBound;
  ArrayData :Pointer;
  TagList :PSafeArray;
  nSize :integer;
begin
  User := Session.GetUser;

  ArrayBounds.lLbound   := 0;
  ArrayBounds.cElements := 0;

  TagList := SafeArrayCreate( varInteger, 1, ArrayBounds );
  User.GetTags( TagList );
  if SafeArrayAccessData( TagList, ArrayData ) = S_OK then
    begin
      nSize := TagList.rgsabound[0].cElements;
      OutLine( '----Available Tags, ' + IntToStr(nSize) + ' tags' );
  for nCnt := 0 to nSize - 1 do
    begin
  OutLine( IntToStr( IntegerArray(ArrayData)[nCnt] ) );
end;
```

OutLine( '----');

SafeArrayUnAccessData( TagList );
  SafeArrayDestroy( TagList );
    end;

end;

Comment: I would imagine it is possible, as long as you don't mind doing it in assembler (the COM dll is unlikely to have symbols embedded in it).

Comment: @forsvarir: thanks for your response. How would I do it in assembler I have never used this before. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @shane87: I haven't tested it, so it might not work, but... set a breakpoint on the line 'photo.GetBinaryData' and run your code to that point.  When the code breaks, right click on the source code window and select 'Go To Disassembly'.  Use the normal F10/F11 keys to step into the calls.  You don't appear to be able to step into all calls (I'm guessing they're kernel code), and I don't have a com dll I can test it on, so it may not work... I'm also a bit sceptical that if it does work it's going to help you very much...

Comment: @forsvarir: Thanks again. this did work but as you said was not very helpful as the code in this file was unreadable with lines of code like the following: " 00000000  mov       qword ptr [rsp+8], rcx 00000005  sub         rsp,0E8h "

Comment: @shane87: *if* you can get an example that works (in .net, or some other language), you may be able to compare the inputs to the one's you're sending from .net, or post on here to get somebody to help with the conversion... good luck

Comment: @shane87: How did you generate the managed type of the `photo` variable you are calling through? What is the IDL of the COM method?

Comment: @shane: COM servers generally contain a type library resource which provides metadata about COM types they expose. You can view the type library using a tool such as the Microsoft SDK OLE-COM Object Viewer OleView.exe (you may have it in your VS tools folder). IDL (Interface Definition Language) is the language used to define COM types etc. The OLEView tool will show you the IDL for the interface you are using. The IDL for the method will tell you exactly what COM/unmanaged types the method expects and outputs.

Comment: @Chris Dickson: I deleted my last comment as I found the IDL for the method.Thanks again for your quick response. I have added the IDL to the original question. Any idea what I should do from here to investagte further?

Comment: @shane: Where did you get the array length (896) from?

Comment: @Chris Dickson: I just randomly set the length to this as I did now know what length to set it. Should I be doing something different?

Comment: @shane: Only the author of the COM method can tell you what the array is supposed to look like when you call it. You say you have some Delphi test code that works... what does that do? On reflection, though, I think you have a more fundamental problem: since the COM method signature accepts `[in]SAFEARRAY(char)` (specifically the [in] bit) I don't think this can work to populate an array allocated by the client, without breaking the semantics of SAFEARRAY. If I'm right, the Delphi code works by accident. I very much doubt you can persuade .NET COM Interop to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, yes, you can step through the code of the COM method implementation instruction-by-instruction.

However, even if you know assembly well and understand exactly how all the processor instructions work, it's a tall order to debug someone else's code in this fashion unless it's a really, really simple method.

If you are new to assembler, don't even consider it unless you're prepared to do weeks of learning curve first.

If the COM method doesn't appear to be working in the way you expected based on its documentation, I would first try to test the method using unmanaged code (e.g. C++), as your problem may be in the COM Interop marshalling rather than in the COM method itself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I don't know assembly I will leave that. The COM dll was written in Delphi and has been tested with delphi code and the method works fine. I presume my problem is with the Interop marshalling. Is there anything I can do to investigate this further?Thanks in advance.