# What happens between the .NET interop layer and COM?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop, tlbimp

I am using COM in my C# .NET project.
However one of the methods I call is not acting as expected.
So I am curious to see what is happening between my .NET code, the Interop layer and COM.
I know the `tlbimp.exe` generates the metadata wrapper for the COM component and I can see these generated methods in the Object browser.
Am I able to see/debug what happens when one of these wrapper methods is called?

I pass an Array to the method below, and expect that this array will be populated, however the Array does not get populated. 
I am calling the following `tlbimp.exe` generated method with unexpected results:

```
int GetTags(System.Array buffer)
    Member of CServer.IUser
```

Method IDL:

```
[id(0x000000d5)]
HRESULT GetTags(
                [in] SAFEARRAY(long) buffer, 
                [out, retval] long* retval);
```

.NET code calling this method:

```
Array tagsArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), tagsLength);
userWrapper.GetTags(tagsArray);
```

Other COM methods I call work fine. However when I call any method which expects an Array as a parameter it does not work as expected.
I am presuming that there is something funny going in with the COM interop marshaller.
So I would like to know if I can see what is happening after I call the `GetTags()` method.

Also I have read the following [here](http://radio-weblogs.com/0105852/stories/2002/11/14/introductionTonetComInterop.html).

`"if you are not satisified with the COM Interop marshaller, you can "override" just about every aspect of it through the very large and useful System::Runtime::InteropServices namespace"`

How can I achieve the above?

**EDIT: Adding a Delphi test script which works**

```
procedure TComTestForm.TestUserBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  nCnt :integer;
  User :IUser;
  Persona :IUserPersona;
  ArrayBounds :TSafeArrayBound;
  ArrayData :Pointer;
  TagList :PSafeArray;
  nSize :integer;
begin
  User := Session.GetUser;

  ArrayBounds.lLbound   := 0;
  ArrayBounds.cElements := 0;

  TagList := SafeArrayCreate( varInteger, 1, ArrayBounds );
  User.GetTags( TagList );
  if SafeArrayAccessData( TagList, ArrayData ) = S_OK then
    begin
      nSize := TagList.rgsabound[0].cElements;
      OutLine( '----Available Tags, ' + IntToStr(nSize) + ' tags' );
  for nCnt := 0 to nSize - 1 do
    begin
      OutLine( IntToStr( IntegerArray(ArrayData)[nCnt] ) );
    end;
  OutLine( '----');

  SafeArrayUnAccessData( TagList );
  SafeArrayDestroy( TagList );
    end;

end;
```

Comment: What kind of error do you have? What is not "working as expected"?

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Thanks for your response. I don't get any error. The method executes fine but the Array does not get populated. The COM code has been tested with delphi and works fine, so this leads me to believe there is something going on in the com-interop layer?

Comment: I think if you want to be able to populate the array in the COM layer, your COM prototype should be different. You need to define the SAFEARRAY by reference or add an [in, out] to the .IDL I suppose. The .NET Marshaler (as any other marshaler BTW) thinks it's a one way call only.

Comment: @Simon: Thank you again for your response. How would I define the SAFEARRAY by reference?. Also if I need to change the IDL does that mean recreating the COM dll?

Comment: yes. see here: http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Passing_Parameter_Arrays_by_Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another update**:
I just realize it might be that you mean that the `GetTags` itself should populate that Array (from the COM code). But this can never work as that parameter is an `[in]` parameter.

For the COM component to be able to fill up that Array, It should be passed as an [in, out] parameter, and by reference (SAFEARRAY*).

---

**Update**: Ok, apparently I was mixing the creation of a COM component in .NET with calling a COM component from .NET.

The CCW (com callable wrapper) indeed takes a .NET Array for COM SafeArray's. I see you create your array in the code in your question, but you don't show how you actually populate it. Maybe something's wrong with that code? Could you share it?

---

Not sure if this is a solution to your problem, but I've experienced problems with COM-interop and SAFEARRAY's in the past.

One thing I learned from it is that the .NET equivalent of a COM SAFEARRAY should always be `object`, so try passing your array as an `object` in stead of as an `Array`.

Comment: The method `GetTags()` will not allow me to pass it an object as it expects a System.Array?

Comment: @shane87: Oh, so that GetTags method in your question is part of the generated (com-interop) code? Then I think the problem is rather with the COM component itself... Do you have access to the code of it?

Comment: @fretje: Yes this method is part of the com-interop code. I do not have access to the code itself but it has been tested by another developer using delphi and everything works fine. So that is why I think that there is something going on in the com-interop layer

Comment: @fretje: Yes what you stated in Another Update, sounds right. Does this mean I should get the COM dll rewritten to accept an out parameter for the SAFEARRAY? does the `*` mean reference?

Comment: @shane: Yes, there is a problem with the interface of the COM dll (are you sure that the Delphi guy tested that same method? About the `*`: it depends in which language the COM component is implemented. I'm familiar with c++, and there the concept of "by value" and "by reference" is totally different than in C#. In c++, I mostly work with `[out, retval, satype(BYTE)] SAFEARRAY** p_Buffer`. So in this case it even needs 2 `*`s to work. I think that's due to the fact that it's also a `[retval]` though, so in your case, if it's only an `[out]` value, I think one will be enough.

Comment: @shane: Just caught up with this new question continuing from your last one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910061/is-it-possible-to-debug-a-com-dll-in-vs2008/5911072#5911072)... fretje is quite right, GetTags cannot in principle work as you are expecting it to. The `*` means pointer: a pointer to the SAFEARRAY is passed on the stack into the method, not the SAFEARRAY structure itself. Since that's not how your GetTags method was written, you can't change the signature to make it accept the SAFEARRAY by reference.

Comment: @fretje/Chris Dickson: Thank you very much for your investigation into this issue. I will get in contact with the developer of the COM dll which was written in delphi and ask him to amend it so that it is an out parameter and by reference. I will post here if all works. Thanks again.

Comment: @shane/fretje: Just to clear up the `*` vs `**` issue: if the client creates the SAFEARRAY, you need one * - a pointer to the SAFEARRAY is passed on the stack. If the method creates the SAFEARRAY (i.e. an [out] method) then you need two ** - the client has to pass on the stack a pointer to a location where the method can write the value of a pointer to the SAFEARRAY.

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to suggest this as an answer, but...

If the Delphi test code really does work, as noted elsewhere, this means the GetTags method must not be playing properly by SAFEARRAY rules. If the COM method is always called in-process, you MAY be able to get the .NET code to work by doing some custom marshalling "by hand", following exactly what the unmanaged Delphi test code does.

As a rough outline, I would imagine that this would involve:

- allocating an unmanaged buffer to hold the array values
- calling Ole Automation SAFEARRAY initialization APIs via P/Invoke to allocate a SAFEARRAY structure and attach the array buffer to it as its pData member
- invoking the GetTags method with this SAFEARRAY
- marshalling your unamanaged buffer into a managed array, before...
- calling the Win32 API to destroy the SAFEARRAY

But much better to get the COM component changed to do things properly, if you can.

Comment: I am waiting to speak to the delphi developer and try get the COM component changed. However when I last spoke he had said that I need to create the SAFEARRAY and pass it to his function as his code does not handle creating/destroying the SAFEARRAY. As this is how he wrote it. I have added the delphi test script(to my questions on this issue) which he tested it with and said it ran fine.